# Proof that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}=2^n$ and implications

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-theorem

Here is a case that I found very interesting:

> Prove that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k} = 2^n$$
> where $n,k\in\mathbb Z^+$

So the proof for this statement is given by what I consider to be one of the most satisfying ones out there:

### Proof

Consider $(x+1)^n$, by the binomial theorem we have: $$(x+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} x^{n-k}1^k$$ $$(x+1)^n={n\choose0}x^{n-0}1^0+{n\choose1}x^{n-1}1^1+{n\choose2}x^{n-2}1^2+\ldots+{n\choose n}x^{n-n}1^n$$ given that $1^k=1$ holds  $\forall k \in \mathbb R$ $$(x+1)^n={n\choose 0}x^n + {n\choose 1}x^{n-1} + {n\choose 2}x^{n-2}+\ldots+{n\choose n}$$ now let $x=1$, hence $(x+1)^n = 2^n$ and $$2^n = {n\choose 0} + {n\choose 1} + {n\choose 2}+\ldots+{n\choose n}$$ $$\implies \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}=2^n$$

The question that I've got is, since I found this case as intriguing as I did, I was wondering what implications this idea has (if any, of course) and whether or not there are any other interesting proofs that sprung from this one, or are similar to this one. Thank you!

Comment: Another proof for the above equality is the counting of the number of subsets of an $n-element$ set; all subsets of size 0, 1, and so on...

Comment: You don't need the $x$ -- just expand $(1+1)^n$ from the beginning.

Comment: This is true, I just did the proof this way originally and kept it this way when typing up the question. Also for the sake of any other proofs that use this logic, I figured the inclusion of the $(x+1)^n$ step might ring some bells :)

Comment: I voted to close this question as "too broad". It is unclear what exactly you're looking for- a lot of proofs look like this (an obvious example would be setting $x=-1$ to prove the alternating binomial identity). There are (probably) tons of interesting proofs that sprung from this one, because this is such a basic result.

Comment: You can also find in a similar way that $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} = 0$.  For $n$ even this may come as a surprise.

Comment: Do you really mean $\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: To my knowledge yes, isn't it true that $x!$ is undefined when $x<0$? @YvesDaoust

Comment: @joshuaheckroodt: that's right, but is doesn't mean that $\binom nk$ isn't... Do you really mean $\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Alright I get your point, but at the same time don't know wha I would replace it with? Would $\mathbb R$ make sense?

Comment: By the way one big implication of this is that a set of $n$ elements has $2^n$ possible subsets.

Answer (score 3):

Here a proof through induction using the recursive relation:

**Base case**: If $n=0$, then $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = \binom{0}{0} = 1 = 2^0.$

**Induction step**: Suppose that the sum $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} = 2^n$, then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k} =2 + \sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n+1}{k} = 2 + \sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k-1} + \sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}$$
$$= 2 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k} + \sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k} = 2 +  2\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} - \binom{n}{0} -\binom{n}{n}$$
$$=2 \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} = 2^{n+1}.$$

Comment: Might I ask where does the $2+\ldots$ come from when you begin expressing $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} {n+1 \choose k}$ ?

Comment: @joshuaheckroodt, that $2$ is the result of $\binom{n + 1}{0} + \binom{n +1}{n + 1}$

Answer (score 3):

This identity is in fact a weakened form of the Binomial theorem,

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk a^kb^{n-k}=(a+b)^n$$ where you just substitute $(1,1)$ for $(a,b)$.

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk=(1+1)^n.$$

Similarly,

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(-1)^k=0.$$

---

The result can also be easily obtained from a well-known property of Pascal's triangle: every element is the sum of the two elements above it (Pascal's rule).

Then the sum of the elements of a row is twice the sum of the elements of the row above.

Comment: I actually haven't heard of the $2^{nd}$ of Pascal's rules, interesting!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proof by double counting:

How can we create a committee of any size from a pool of $n$ candidates? We can separate this into the cases where the committee is of size $k$, of which there are $\binom{n}{k}$ such committees. Summing over all values of $k$ accounts for all sizes of the committee to obtain $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}$ total committees. Another answer to the question is to look at each candidate and decide whether or not they are on the committee. There are two options per person: on the committee or not, so there are $2^n$ ways to choose this committee of arbitrary size. Hence, $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}=2^n$.

I don't know of any proofs coming out of the one you give, but we can use the binomial theorem to develop more identities similar to what you have. For instance, putting $x=1,y=-1$ into the binomial theorem formula, we have $0=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k$.